# How off is my understanding of Lambert's theorem to solve Lambert's Problem?

Tags: physics, conic-sections, celestial-mechanics

Math Overflow-ites! Hopefully, this question fits here better than places like Space and Physics. And sorry if I ramble a little - I'm rather new to this all.

My understanding of Lambert's theorem is that the time of flight of a transfer orbit depends on **only** on the semi-major axis, the sum of the radii and the linear distance between both points. I've seen equations roughly like these:
$$
T = F(r_{1} + r_{2}, a, c).
$$
What I have read is that since the time does **not** depend on the eccentricity, so I'm pretty sure that you can change the eccentricity while keeping these three parameters the same and the value of $T$ would remain the same.

So if I 'squash' the elliptic orbit with the same parameters into a perfect circle, it makes sense that the problem is still solvable, except that instead of a phase difference of $\theta$ there's a phase change of $\Phi$, and if I can find it I would have an easier time calculating $T$, because its a circular orbit.

And if it is a circular orbit I can redefine the distances to the start and destination as $r'$, such that:

$$2r'= r_{1} + r_{2} $$ and $$a = \frac{r_{1} + r_{2}}{2}$$

And if you equate the different values of $c^2$, you should be able to calculate $\Phi$ from $r_1$, $r_2$, $\theta$ and $a$.
$$
2a^{2}\big(1 - \cos(\Phi)\big) = r_{1}^2 + r_{2}^2 - 2r_{1}r_{1}\cos(\theta).
$$ 
And if I can find what $\Phi$ is from numerical methods I can find what $T$ is from my value for the semi-major axis and the gravitational constant.

However, for some reason, this does not work, and I'm not very sure why. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not that it's very important, but this site is not Math Overflow...

Comment: How can a circular orbit be possible, if $r_1\ne r_2$?